# Bit.ly link to Number of Facebook Likes and Twitter mentions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-like, bit.ly

Programatically,
How can I get the canonical link from bit.ly?
How can I get the number of facebook likes given a canonical link?
How can I get the number of twitter mentions given a canonical link?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take a http://bit.ly/s.... link and get the original, long URL, then find out the number of likes for that long link on Facebook, and tweets containing it on Twitter. Is that all about right?

For the first part, you can use the [link info](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_info) API to get the long URL from bitly. It may or may not be "canonical," though. It'll just be what was shortened. So it might have extra campaign parameters.

Community Wiki in case people can help with the second two parts of the questions.